# Where did this "nonexistant" directory come from and what should I do with it?

Tags: filesystem, root

It's owned by 'nobody' and I'm wondering if it could explain difficulty I'm having in shutting down.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Nov 28 09:59 bin  
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root 4.0K Jan 16 08:28 boot  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Mar 31  2012 cdrom  
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   root 4.4K Jan 16 13:23 dev  
drwxr-xr-x 175 root   root  12K Jan 16 13:24 etc  
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   root 4.0K May 22  2012 home  
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   37 Jan 13 12:34 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic-pae  
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   37 Oct 15 19:01 initrd.img.old -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic-pae  
drwxr-xr-x  25 root   root 4.0K Jan 16 08:25 lib  
drwx------   2 root   root  16K Mar 31  2012 lost+found  
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   root 4.0K Jan 16 13:17 media  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Jan 27  2012 mnt  
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody root 4.0K Oct 22 17:53 nonexistent  
drwxr-xr-x  34 root   root 4.0K Nov  5 19:09 opt  
dr-xr-xr-x 222 root   root    0 Jan 16 13:21 proc  
drwx------  20 root   root 4.0K Jan 14 23:26 root  
drwxr-xr-x  28 root   root  980 Jan 16 13:22 run  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root  12K Jan 15 18:42 sbin  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Mar  5  2012 selinux  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Mar 28  2012 srv  
drwxr-xr-x  13 root   root    0 Jan 16 13:21 sys  
drwxrwxrwt  13 root   root 4.0K Jan 16 13:33 tmp  
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   root 4.0K Oct 26 22:36 usr  
drwxr-xr-x  14 root   root 4.0K Jan 16 13:21 var  
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   33 Jan 13 12:34 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic-pae  
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   33 Oct 15 19:01 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
```

As requested

```
jarlath@jarlath-EP35-DS3:~$ ls -la /nonexistent/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody root 4096 Oct 22 17:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root   root 4096 Jan 13 12:34 ..
```

Comment: Can you post the output of ls -la /nonexistant/ in the question. This might help identify what service is causing any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about the nobody username here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_%28username%29

The folder nonexistent gets created when someone tries to use the nobody username. Its like the /home/nobody/ directory - but obviously it shouldn't normally exist. It would be worth checking what files are in that directory to see if there is a problem with a particular service. Spamassassin or sshd for example, both use the nobody username.

Comment: It's empty actually.

Comment: Its probably safe to delete then.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if it was connected to an issue I was having but it seems to be a harmless behaviour.